# Swift Take a string, and return every string wrapped in "%%" bold, and everything else leave as is

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a .txt file, and I have some words wrapped with `"%%"` on both sides (e.g. `"My Regular text, and %%my Bold text%%"`). I want it to return `"My Regular text, and`**my Bold text**`"`

How would I set ALL wrapped text to be bold?

Answer (score 1):

A string of text does not in itself contain any formatting information. No fonts, no weights, no styles, etc...

What you are looking for is NSAttributedString. Using this you can then add attributes to substrings to add bolder text.

I believe it now supports markdown too so you can use double asterisks **like this** to make text bold without having to do much yourself.

I’ll find a link.

A popular iOS framework for Swift is Down https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Down

Comment: How do I use it?

Comment: @BugWarrior check out the instructions on the github page to install it using Cocoapods. Then the read me has all the instructions you need to use it.

Comment: I have downloaded Down, I put it into my workspace in my project, but I can't figure out how to implement it into my code. I tried importing it like this `import Down`, and this `import XCTest @testable import Down`.

Comment: Did you not read when I said to install via cocoa pods? It’s much easier to use that way. Then read the readme from the git page about how to use it.

Comment: Okay, I've installed cocoa pods, I used it to get a pod in my project, but I still can't get Down to work.

Comment: Did you open the workspace file? Did you `import Down`? When you say “can’t get it to work” what do you mean? Have you tried to get it to work? Have you written any code?

Comment: @BugWarrior did you try the syntax from the readme... `let down = Down(markdownString: theString)` and then ... `let atteibutedString = try? down.toAttributedString()`? All of this is in the readme of the framework. It has detailed instructions of how to use the framework.

Comment: I opened the workspace file. What I mean by "can't get Down to work" is I can't import it. Yes I have tried. Yes I have written code:```let down = Down(markdownString:String)```, and ```let attributedString = try? down.toAttributedString()```. The problem is importing Down, it says ```No such module Down```.